# Power automate cloud - union on single item

Tags: power-automate

I'm doing a union (using select) in power automate to get the unique entries of two json objects

union(body('ExistingRoutes'),body('ImportedRoutes'))

```
{
  description: Blah123
  value: 123
}
{
  description: Blah123456
  value: 123
}
{
  description: Test456
  value: 456
}
{
  description: Check432
  value: 432
}
```

What it currently does will give me 4 entries in my select output, but what I would like is for it to only match no the value so my list would look like (basically just pick one of them, don't really care which one)

```
{
  description: Blah123
  value: 123
}
{
  description: Test456
  value: 456
}
{
  description: Check432
  value: 432
}
```

I previously used an apply to all - and it took 10+ mins to run compared to sub second for the select so don't really want to go back to that if i can avoid it

Have tried a number of variations of the select's formula but all error out

```
union(body('ExistingRoutes')?['value'], body('ImportedRoutes')?['value'])
```

```
union(body('ExistingRoutes')?['items'], body('ImportedRoutes')?['items'])
```

```
union(
    select(body('ExistingRoutes')?['items'], 'value'),
    select(body('ImportedRoutes')?['items'], 'value')
)
```

```
union(
    select(json(body('ExistingRoutes'))?['items'], 'value'),
    select(json(body('ImportedRoutes'))?['items'], 'value')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple of caveats in your question, the most important one being that you didn't want to go back to a 10 minute + run time so because of that, my suggestion is to use the `Advanced Data Operations` connector (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/advanceddataoperatio/) as it has some really useful actions for doing what you need AND others that may come in handy in the future.

It can be achieved via a couple of ways but the easiest is to use the `Expert` operation.

[image: Expert]

Using the SQL statement as shown in the image over your small dataset ...

```
SELECT [description], [value]
FROM ( SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [value]) AS [RowNumber], *
    FROM [Data]) AS [Source]
WHERE [Source].[RowNumber] = 1
```

... I was able to extract what you needed, and it only took 1 second.

[image: Result]

This was the resulting JSON ...

```
[
  {
    "description": "Blah123",
    "value": 123
  },
  {
    "description": "Check432",
    "value": 432
  },
  {
    "description": "Test456",
    "value": 456
  }
]
```

The only real catch here is that it's not free (although very cheap) and you will need a premium licence in PowerAutomate to consume.

Comment: That's not the behaviour I'm observing today with UNION, it is removing the duplicates but both fields must match

Comment: Oh well there you go.  I guess I've never encountered that.  I'll amend my answer.